# Empty 70-persistent-net.rules directory

Tags: linux, udev

I am using the bento/centos-7.5 box in vagrant. When it comes up, there is an empty directory in the path /etc/udev/rulesd/70-persistent-net.rules/.

Isn't 70-persistent-net.rules supposed to be a file? This causes issues when I am creating the actual 70-persistent-net.rules using puppet as it fails saying there is a directory with the same name in the path. I had to manually remove the empty directory on start of the vagrant box to make it work.

My question is why is an empty directory getting created instead of a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something, probably Vagrant's provisioning scripts, is deliberately creating a directory so that udev's original rules wouldn't be able to create a file and put automatic rules in there.

(Recall that Debian generates 70-persistent-net such that interface names are assigned by MAC address, which was probably deemed unsuitable for transient VMs with dynamic MAC addresses on every reboot.)

Of course, a better solution would have been to remove the scripts which *generate* this file to begin with, but that would have required work...

---

In the mean time, you can just use a different name, such as `71-persistent-net.rules`, for your own rules.

Comment: You mean the provisioning scripts for the box right? Because I don't see the same happening when I use a different box like `centos/7`